# Need help in Gmail Integration in my Application

Tags: php, api, email, gmail, imap

I want to integrate Gmail (googleApps) into my application. I have created a PHP Imap library which will give me my required emails it is very slow and takes a lot of time during execution. I heard that Gmail (googleApps) is beginning to provide an interface that we can directly show in our web page. If we have something like this by using any third party API or google API please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at gmails http api for mail, which is geared towards web services?

Answer (score -1):

I will give you a short answer. You don't have a detailed question you want someone to help you find something? Then maybe this is what you are looking for:

Google for

> walsh gmail-php-imap

Comment: I had already visited that site many times. Walsh created a good script for listing inbox but that is not exactly i am looking at. I want a widget or API type thing whose execution is fast as compare to PHP IMAP functions.